# Iterate through folders, then subfolders and print filenames with path to text file

Tags: directory, python-2.6, subdirectory

I am trying to use python to create the files needed to run some other software in batch.
For part of this I need to produce a text file that loads the needed data files into the software. 
My problem is that the files I need to enter into this text file are stored in a set of structured folders.

I need to loop over a set of folders (up to 20), which each could contain up to 3 more folders which contain the files I need. The bottom level of the folders contain a set of files needed for each run of the software. The text file should have the path+name of these files printed line by line, add an instruction line and then move to the next set of files from a folder and so on until all of sub level folders have been checked.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use os.walk(). The following will output a list of all files within the subdirectories of "dir". The results can be manipulated to suit you needs:

```
import os                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                      
def list_files(dir):                                                                                                  
    r = []                                                                                                            
    subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]                                                                            
    for subdir in subdirs:                                                                                            
        files = os.walk(subdir).next()[2]                                                                             
        if (len(files) > 0):                                                                                          
            for file in files:                                                                                        
                r.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))                                                                         
    return r
```

For python 3, change `next()` to `__next__()`.

Comment: What if the dir path is in ADLS? How can we walk through adls folder using python?

Answer (score 85):

Charles' answer is good, but can be improved upon to increase speed and efficiency. Each item produced by os.walk() (See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)) is a tuple of three items. Those items are:

1. The working directory
2. A list of strings naming any sub-directories present in the working directory
3. A list of files present in the working directory

Knowing this, much of Charles' code can be condensed with the modification of a forloop:

```
import os

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r
```

Comment: so what's the diff btwn root and dir? and what should i put for dir? the parent folder of all the sub folders i want to walk through right? this code is not working for me :( returning empty array...

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions `root` is the first item of a tuple generated by `os.walk()`. `dir` is the directory of the files you want to iterate through. In my answer's code, the subfolders (indicated by tuple item `dirs`) are ignored. Only the files and their root directories are used.

Comment: Just use a list comprehension: `return [os.path.join(r, n) for r, _, f in os.walk(dir) for n in f]`.

Answer (score 2):

This will help to list specific file extension. In my sub-folders i have many files but i am only interested parquet files.

```
import os
dir = r'/home/output/'
def list_files(dir):
r = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
        if filepath.endswith(".snappy.parquet"):
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
return r
```