# delete string from multiple XML files using Python

Tags: python, xml

i want to delete the string below from every XML file in every subfolder of R:/processed. I'm new to programming using Python and have no idea where to start :(

resources

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you post an example of the xml looks like? Best bet is to examine the xml and look for a pattern you can take advantage of that relates to what you want to get rid of.

Comment: Try an xml parsing library. I recommend elementree, but there are a few other good ones.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Use the os library to iterate through the files in R:/processed. For every file, edit the xml:

`import os
files = os.listdir('R:/processed')
for f in files: do_something(f)`

Comment: This has a good example of iterating through directories and subdirectories:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932130/python-iterate-through-folders-then-subfolders-and-print-filenames-with-path-t