# Python - loop through subfolders and files in a directory without ignoring the subfolder

Tags: python, subdirectory

I have read all the stack exchange help files on looping through subfolders, as as well as the os documentation, but I am still stuck. I am trying to loop over files in subfolders, open each file, extract the first number in the first line, copy the file to a different subfolder(with the same name but in the output directory) and rename the file copy with the number as a suffix.

```
import os
import re
outputpath = "C:/Users/Heather/Dropbox/T_Files/Raw_FRUS_Data/Wisconsin_Copies_With_PageNumbers"
inputpath = "C:/Users/Heather/Dropbox/T_Files/Raw_FRUS_Data/FRUS_Wisconsin"
suffix=".txt" 
for root, dirs, files  in os.walk(inputpath):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        foldername=os.path.split(os.path.dirname(file_path))[1]
        filebname=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        filename=filebname + "_"
        f=open(os.path.join(root,file),'r')
        data=f.readlines()
        if data is None:
            f.close() 
        else:
            with open(os.path.join(root,file),'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    s=re.search(r'\d+',line)
                    if s:
                        pagenum=(s.group())
                        break
        with open(os.path.join(outputpath, foldername,filename+pagenum+suffix), 'w') as f1:
            with open(os.path.join(root,file),'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    f1.write(line)
```

I expect the result to be copies of the files in the input directory placed in the corresponding subfolder in the output directory, renamed with a suffix, such as "005_2", where 005 is the original file name, and 2 is the number the python code extracted from it.

The error I get seems to indicates that I am not looping through files correctly. I know the code for extracting the first number and renaming the file works because I tested it on a single file. But using os.walk to loop through multiple subfolders is not working, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-614e2851f16a>", line 23, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(outputpath, foldername,filename+pagenum+suffix), 'w') as f1:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Heather/Dropbox/T_Files/Raw_FRUS_Data/Wisconsin_Copies_With_PageNumbers\\FRUS_Wisconsin\\.dropbox_1473986809.txt'
```

Comment: Does the "FRUS_Wisconsin" directory exist before you run the code?

Comment: You are probably trying to copy a temp file that doesn't exist anymore. Are you sure you are interested in the files starting with a `.` dot

Comment: You are going to need to check if a subfolder exists, if not, create it, then write. Or re-create the directory structure in your target path before running the above code, perhaps.

Comment: Also, are there files *in* `FRUS_Wisconsin` that you want to copy? Or only subdirectories?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932130/python-iterate-through-folders-then-subfolders-and-print-filenames-with-path-t

Comment: Also, windows path delimiters are `\\ ` so it should be `C:\\Users\\Heather\\ `

Comment: Would you mind iterating through some example directory structures with your program and outputting the results? Specifically, I'd be interested in a directory without temp files (any file starting with a dot).

Comment: @JakobLovern I was about to say they should give us the output of `tree` but then I saw it was a Windows path ... anyone know of a similar command-line utility for `cmd` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It looks like DOS/NT also have a command named `tree` that does the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Both the input and output directories have several hundred subfolders with the same names, each with several hundred files. I want to copy the files from the old directory to the new one, but put them in the same subfolder. Yes, I already created this outside of this code. I don't know if there are temp files -- I certainly don't see any.

Comment: @HeatherBa so the output directory already has the same sub-directory structure, just no files?

Comment: Yes, the output directory has the same sub-directory structure but no files -- just empty folders.

Comment: Is there a way to tell python to ignore temporary files?

Comment: There are no files outside of the subfolders within each directory -- the files only exist in the subfolders in the input directoryl

Comment: I think fundamentally the problem is that `foldername` will always contain just whatever the immediate parent name is, so `C:/path/to/myfile.txt`, then `foldername` will be `'to'`, however, if you go deeper than one level, `os.path.join(outputpath, foldername,filename+pagenum+suffix)` will be incorrect, you need to keep track of the directory names and append those to `outputpath`.

Comment: Also, it is failing *on the first iteration anyway*, because `FRUS_Wisconsin` is being appended to the `Wisconsin_Copies_With_PageNumbers`, but presumably, those two should be equivalent levels? Try putting everything under a `FRUS_Wisconsin` path  *in* `Wisconsin_Copies_With_PageNumbers` that or special case the root directory....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- ok. that would make sense. What's the best way to do that? Keep track of the folder names,  I mean.

Comment: @HeatherBa trying to think of an elegant solution, I'm leaning towards just using two iterators: `wsource, wtarget = os.walk(inputpath), os.walk(outputpath)`, then `for (root, dirs, files), (target_root, _, _) in zip(wsource, wtarget): ... ` but I'm not sure if you can rely on the iterators walking the paths in the same order...

Comment: Another less satisfying approach would be not to pass the absolute path to `os.walk`, if you can use the source directory as the working directory, pass `os.walk('./')` or whatever the windows equivalent would be... but then, `root` will always bee *relative* to that, so you could concatenate `outputpath + root + directory` maybe.

Comment: Aha! If you are sure that the directory structure is *exactly the same*, `os.walk` will recurse in the order that `dirs` returns, so just make sure to add a `dirs.sort()` on every iteration, and the two-iterator approach should work! so `for (root, dirs, files), (troot,tdirs,_) in zip(...)` then use `dirs.sort()` and `tdirs.sort()` and use `troot` when you try to open the target-file.

Comment: When I run the following code, it prints a list of all the subdirectories, but substituting this into my code above, I still get an error.
    inputpath = 
 "C:\\Users\\Heather\\Dropbox\\Tim_McKeown_Files\\Raw_FRUS_Data\\
    FRUS_Wisconsin"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputpath):
        for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        wkspFldr = str(file_path.split('\\')[7])
        print(wkspFldr)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks you. I've never used itertools before. Struggling to get the code right. Any more specific help you could give would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't eloquent, but it worked

```
from glob import glob
folderlist=glob("C:\\...FRUS_Wisconsin*\\")
outputpath = "C:\\..\Wisconsin_Copies_With_PageNumbers"
for folder in folderlist:
    foldername = str(folder.split('\\')[7])
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            filebname=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            filename=filebname + "_"
            if not filename.startswith('._'):
                with open(os.path.join(root,file),'r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        s=re.search(r'\d+',line)
                        if s:
                           pagenum=(s.group())
                           break
                     with open(os.path.join(outputpath, foldername,filename+pagenum+suffix), 'w') as f1:
                        with open(os.path.join(root,file),'r') as f:
                            for line in f:
                                f1.write(line)
```