# How to do computations through directory and subfolders

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

I have one main directory which has 9 subfolders. Inside of each of them, there are 1000 files. I needed to do a for loop for reading main directory and folders but the problem is that, subfolder names are not similar and don't have a numerator and I got stuck. I have seen [Iterate through folders, then subfolders and print filenames with path to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932130/iterate-through-folders-then-subfolders-and-print-filenames-with-path-to-text-f) but I could not distinguish how to get started.
My effort is below:

```
import os                                                                                                             

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\Desktop\output\new our scenario\test'):
     for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as auto:
            ##Doing Whatever I want
```

But it's not correct and does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a directory and sub-folders python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933842/how-to-read-a-directory-and-sub-folders-python)

Comment: please, avoid asking the same question again and again.

Comment: `'\Desktop\output\new our scenario\test'` is unlikely to exist on your PC, please, check that again.

Comment: @lenik now, I have to delete this question or I can keep it, what is your advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know `glob`? That might be a solution to your problem.

You can get a list of all files in subdirectories by using wildcard path names, e.g.:

Here is an example for looping through txt files, but you do not necessarily restrict it to a file type. But if you do not use `*.*` at the end it will also list dirs

```py
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('known_dir/*/*.txt')

for file in file_list:
    with open(file, "r") as auto:
         ##Doing Whatever you want
```